# Docker gives an error trying to create aufs mount

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, docker, arm

On Ubuntu Bionic ARM64 on my Raspberry Pi 4b I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: error creating aufs mount to /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ae6dd4e40cc4ee953f997a4f19f8056efe077eba1603cca2cfb7350c93969edb-init: mount target=/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ae6dd4e40cc4ee953f997a4f19f8056efe077eba1603cca2cfb7350c93969edb-init data=br:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/ae6dd4e40cc4ee953f997a4f19f8056efe077eba1603cca2cfb7350c93969edb-init=rw:/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/c1d12d7d4632739ca4f5577690e026706470b0e3fb32dfa1544095d23755b1e8=ro+wh,dio,xino=/dev/shm/aufs.xino: invalid argument.
```

I'm running docker-ce. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by Berryboot which uses AUFS itself apparently and you cannot have AUFS on AUFS (this error) nor can you switch to the alternative overlay2 storage driver.
I now switched to using devicemapper as the storage driver and that seems to work. In the end I hope to be able to boot directly from USB and just be able to use overlay2 then but for now this works.