# Why can't Docker use aufs or overlay2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker

In reference to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1493385/docker-gives-an-error-trying-to-create-aufs-mount), the only answer states you can't use aufs or overlay2 with berryboot on raspberry pi.  I want to know why I can't use at least overlay2?

Answer (score 0):

The various storage drivers in docker are built on various Linux filesystems, like Overlay and AUFS. Each of these filesystems have their own requirements, and in particular, they depend on a specific backing filesystem on the host. For overlay2, that backing filesystem must be ext4 or xfs (with ftype=1). To see more on the various storage drivers and their requirements, see [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-backing-filesystems).